# crashing event with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am working on a simple pygame project and it currently has falling bombs which come from the top of the screen and head to the bottom of the screen. If the player hits the bomb they die. Everything works good up to this point. The problem is that when the bomb has passed the player, but not yet left the screen, it will still kill the player. Meaning, the bomb will have passed the lower portion of the player but if you cross, before it crosses the lower part of the screen, you will die. He is my code:

```
   if player.rect.y < thing_starty + thing_height:
        if player.rect.x > thing_startx and player.rect.x < thing_startx + thing_width or player.rect.x  + 28 > thing_startx and player.rect.x  + 28 < thing_startx + thing_width: 
            gameOver = True
```

the values are as follows:

```
thing_startx = random.randrange(0, S_WIDTH)
thing_starty = -300
thing_speed = 3
thing_width = 128
thing_height = 128
```

the value for player.rect.x ranges from 120 to 500 depending on where the player is on the screen. (The screen will scroll from the left to the right as you move as well.) The 28 comes from the width of the character image.

the code for the falling object is the following:

```
if thing_starty > S_HEIGHT:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(bomb_sound)
        thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
        thing_startx = random.randrange(0, S_WIDTH)
        dodged += 1
        thing_speed += .5
```

I have been working on this for about a week and have made no progress. Thank you for any help.

Comment: pygame has [pygame.Rect()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep object position and size, and [one_rect.colliderect(other_rect)](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to check collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neal already said, you just check for the y value being greater than the player's y value.

But my advice is, stop using code like this:

```
 if player.rect.y < thing_starty + thing_height:
    if player.rect.x > thing_startx and player.rect.x < thing_startx + thing_width or player.rect.x  + 28 > thing_startx and player.rect.x  + 28 < thing_startx + thing_width: 
        gameOver = True
```

and take a look at the [documentation for the `Rect` class](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to find a lot of handy functions, like [`colliderect`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect).

Use a `Rect` to represent the position of your bomb* also (like you to for `player`), and you can use code like this:

```
if player.rect.colliderect(thing.rect):
    gameOVer = True
```

---

* which should probably have it's own class, inherited from `Sprite`, but that's another topic

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but it is clear that your conditional statement that you are using to test for collision is simply checking if the y value is greater than the player's y value, which will, of course, be true even after it passes the bottom of the screen.  So you need an AND operand in there somewhere.

pseudocode (because I don't know python... or whatever you are using)

```
if (bomb.y >= player.y AND bomb.y <= player.y + player.height){
    run bomb hits player logic
}
```

or if you don't want to use an AND operand (it won't be AND, but each language has its own version of this) then you can just use a nested conditional block like this

psuedocode

```
if (bomb.y >= player.y){
    if (bomb.y <= player.y + player.height){
        run bomb collision logic
    }
 }
```

this way the collision logic doesn't run if the bomb is below the player/ off screen.  Of course, it also needs to pass the x position test, but you seem to already have that sorted out.